# to implement series of Checkboxes using layout inflater

Tags: android

```
1.LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

2.LayoutInflater layoutinflater=getLayoutInflater();

3.View v=layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.c,null);

4.linear.addView(v);
```

'c' is my child layout name.
I'am getting error (NullPointerException) in the fourth line...

I want to inflate a list of checkboxes.
what can I do...?

Comment: Did you set content view before you find LinearLayout1?

Comment: Nope....how to set it?

Comment: Do you use setContentView() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
LinearLayout linear= new LinearLayout(this);

setContentView(linear);

LayoutInflater layoutinflater=getLayoutInflater();

View v=layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.c,null);

linear.addView(v);
```

Also you can try that

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);

LinearLayout linear= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

LayoutInflater layoutinflater=getLayoutInflater();

View v=layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.c,null);

linear.addView(v);
```